# Embedding Apple maps into QtWidget by mixing cocoa and qt

Tags: c++, macos, qt, cocoa, maps

I see that it is possible to combine cocoa with qt and have done so for really basic things like displaying cocoa style text fields using QMacCocoaViewContainer.

I now want to embed apple maps to display a 3d map in my qt desktop application. How can I go about doing this by using cocoa code in Qt? should I just write the same code I would write for doing it in Xcode for an IOS/OSX application?
how can I import things like 'MapKit' into Qt?

Thanks